# Why I am getting NaN from useRef in react native TextInput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Hi Below is a code in which there is two Text Input from react-native and a button when I click the button the result should generate that the two numbers come from the two Text Input but I am getting `Nan`.

But the code should give me a number that means Text Input

```js
console.log(+refNum1.current.value) // giving me NaN
```

Comment: What is `refNum1` initialized to? Please share your full code

Comment: The + at the start is the reason it's giving NaN, remove it to console.log the value

Answer (score 0):

I beleive your .value is of type string. Convert it to an integer with the `parseInt()` function.

E.g.

`ParseInt(myNumber)`

Comment: i already have convert into integer by applying parsInt() but result is not a number (Nan)

Answer (score 0):

Make it something like this

Working Example [here](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/textinput-value)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const TextInputRef_1 = React.useRef();
  const TextInputRef_2 = React.useRef();
  const [Result, SetResult] = React.useState('');

  const Generate = () => {
    // Do whatever you like with values
    const a = parseInt(TextInputRef_1.current.value);
    const b = parseInt(TextInputRef_2.current.value);

    console.log('Sum = ', a + b);
    console.log('Difference = ', a - b);
    console.log('Product = ', a * b);
    console.log('Division = ', a / b);

    SetResult(
      `Sum = ${a + b}\nDifference =  ${a - b}\nProduct =  ${
        a * b
      }\nDivision =  ${a / b}`
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Enter 1st Number"
        ref={TextInputRef_1}
        style={styles.TextInput}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Enter 2nd Number"
        ref={TextInputRef_2}
        style={styles.TextInput}
      />
      <Button title="Generate" onPress={() => Generate()} />

      <Text>{Result}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  TextInput: {
    width: '100%',
    marginBottom: 12,
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 12,
  },
});
```